# Do they refer to Albert Einstein on planet Krypton in Superman?

Tags: dc, superman, superman-1978

My recollection of the original Superman movie with Christopher Reeves shows baby Superman heading to earth in a rocketship.  Along the way the rocketship talks to Superman teaching him things.  At one point the rocketship says "according to Einstein's theory of Relativity..."  Is my memory correct?  And why would planet Krypton's physicist just happen to have the same name as planet earth's physicist?

Comment: Like in Quantum Physics where particles are entangled in very large distances maybe the quantum physics apply to the whole universe whatever happens on earth also happens on different planets same people etc haha.

Comment: I have the exact same memory. I always assumed that Jor-El simply had enough knowledge of earth to use human terminology, but I have no knowledge of whether this makes any sense within the logic of the universe established in the comics. Another possibility is he is actually speaking Kryptonian and "Einstein's theory of relativity" is the just the English translation of the Kryptonian word for the idea that space and time distort as one's velocity approaches the speed of light.

Comment: I was under the impression that the pod was teaching him about Earth's current level of scientific knowledge

Comment: I don't remember this scene, but alien speech is often translated onscreen to English, for the benefit of Earth viewers. And it may not just be the words, but the concepts, the ideas, that are translated into something we are familiar with. So whatever they call the theory, it will be referred to as "Einstein's theory of relativity.

Comment: The dialog is [in the shooting script](http://www.supermanhomepage.com/movies/superman_I_shoot.txt) **COMPUTER (JOR-EL'S voice)** "*...which Einstein called his Theory of Relativity, mistakenly held to be correct until the year ...*"

Comment: The [movie transcript](http://www.supermanhomepage.com/movies/movies.php?topic=m-movie1-transcript) reads differently: "*...which Einstein called his Theory of Relativity. Embedded in the crystals before you, is the total accumulation of all literature and scientific fact from dozens of other worlds, spanning the 28 known galaxies...*"

Comment: The dialog of the shooting script is really curious because it implies some sort of time travel must be involved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The answer is **yes**, they certainly do refer to "Einstein" in the film Superman but they're referring to **the Earth scientist Albert Einstein** rather than a Kryptonian with the same name.

The original [shooting script](http://www.supermanhomepage.com/movies/superman_I_shoot.txt) contains a number of key pieces of monologue (edited by me for brevity) that indicate that young Kal-el is being spoonfed a potted history of Earth's science, history and culture of which we are hearing a few snippets;

> **34 INT. MODULE** Lights flash on the complex instrument panel. A computer memory bank repeats recorded data while machines registers
>   other space functions on graphs. The baby is completely wired and
>   fitted with instruments and tubes for his survival in space. The
>   computer spews forth information.
>
> **COMPUTER : (JOR-EL'S VOICE) :** *Early concepts of matter appear in ancient Greek philosophy. In the fifth century Demoocritus defined a
>   small unit as an atom, then thought to be indivisible...*
>
> **35 EXT. SPACE** - The module voyages through space.
>
> **INT MODULE: COMPUTER (JOR-EL'S voice)** *Index 19, Sonnet 101: "O truant muse, what shall be thy amends for thy neglect of truth in
>   beauty dyed?*
>
> **38 INT. MODULE - COMPUTER (JOR-EL'S voice)** *...which Einstein called his Theory  of Relativity, mistakenly held to be correct until
>   the year...*

[image]

Although the actual [transcript](http://www.supermanhomepage.com/movies/movies.php?topic=m-movie1-transcript) is slightly different, the principle is basically the same;

> **INT. SHIP : COMPUTER: (JOR-EL'S voice) :** ...**which Einstein called his Theory of Relativity**. *Embedded in the crystals before
>   you, is the total accumulation of all literature and scientific fact
>   from dozens of other worlds, spanning the 28 known galaxies...*
>
> **INT. SHIP : COMPUTER: (JOR-EL'S voice) :** *Early Chinese writings point out the complex relationship between...(later)...By carrying
>   this complex equation to its ultimate power, one can...(later)...Chief
>   among these powers will be your sight, your strength, your hearing.
>   Your ability to propel yourself at almost limitless
>   speed...(later)...The early history of our universe was a bloody
>   mosaic of interplanetary war...(later)...each of the six galaxies
>   which you will pass through contain their own individual
>   law...(later)...space and time. It is forbidden for you to interfere
>   with human history...*

Comment: "Mistakenly thought to be correct until the year ..."  So they know earth's past AND future?  (BTW the universe's supposed lack of compliance with GR turned out to be because of dark matter, not any flaw in GR.  So GR withstands the test of time thus far.)

Answer (score 4):

If you remember back when clark kent goes the the fortress of solitude for the first time, he spends several years with his father learning about all of the known Galaxies and so on.  Jor El chose to send Clark to Earth when their planet was dying.  Therefor they already knew everything about earth, including the history that goes along with it.  So to me, it would make sense to teach Clark of history involving things/people/and so on from earth.  So they were really talking about Albert Einstein.   They have information from 1000's of different planets and species.  Makes sense that he teaches Clark of things from Earth since he will be living there.  Hope this just made sense